# Installing Ubuntu for the first time

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

I am someone new to Ubuntu and installing it for the first time. I have downloaded "ubuntu 14.10 desktop i386.iso" for intel x86, and I want to install it on my Intel core i5 (Is this selection right? ). As I was going through the guides for installation I found the term "a bootable USB" which I clearly understand, but I wanted to ask if once I boot the USB to install the OS, for each and every-time I want to run Ubuntu would I have to connect the "booted USB" ??

Comment: Not an answer but if you have an intel core i5, you probably have 4 or  more GB of RAM, and you should probably be using the 64 bit version of Ubuntu. The 32 bit (x86) will still work well but with it you won't be using all your CPU capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

No. The bootable USB is just for installation and can be removed afterwards. Once installed, Ubuntu will boot from the hard disk.